# How can I put quotes in a string?

Tags: c#, string, quotes

I need to write a string literal to a text file, but the C# compiler finds errors when I use quote characters in it.

My current code:

```
writeText.WriteLine("<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>");
```

I need the output for the text file to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

How can I put quote characters in strings in C#?

Comment: If you are creating XML then you shouldn't use a text writer like that. Use an `XmlWriter` instead to generate the XML correctly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to escape the quotation marks to put them in a string. There is two ways of doing this. Using backslashes in a regular string:

```
writeText.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
```

Using double quoation marks in a @-delimited string:

```
writeText.WriteLine(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>");
```

Comment: The second form (@-delimited string) is called a verbatim string literal
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: That documentation link has been retired, try [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string).

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
writeText.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
```

Have a look at "What character escape sequences are available?" of the [C# FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20151019035344/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88415.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, you really should 'accept' answers, in this case mine or Guffas, they are both correct :)

Comment: yes both of you r right.but some times i was too busy..to do it..i really sorry for that..thanks for remind me..

Answer (score 3):

Since to XML both " and ' can used, try

```
writeText.WriteLine("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>");
```