# How to include quotes in a string

Tags: c#, string, double-quotes

I have a string "I want to learn "c#"".  How can I include the quotes before and after c#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I put quotes in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911073/how-can-i-put-quotes-in-a-string)

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Escape them with backslashes.

```
"I want to learn \"C#\""
```

Comment: The reference manual is helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx

Comment: you cannot use multiple """ when formatting a string String.Format("<E><A KH=\"{0}\" ID=\"{1}\"/><C><T ID=\"{2}\" SID=\"{3}\"><L P=\"{4}\" N=\"{5}\" /></T></C></E>", params) will not work with multiple quotes. please use this answer that is marked correctly and get used to the habit of doing it.

Comment: @ANeves  fair to say  that @newbee is wrong and that  there's a Working counter-example: `string ok = string.Format(@"""{0}"" = {1}", "yes", true);` but don't link to stupid irrelevant pictures that waste peoples' time. This is a technical site

Answer (score 109):

As well as escaping quotes with backslashes, also see SO question [2911073](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911073/how-can-i-put-quotes-in-a-string) which explains how you could alternatively use double-quoting in a @-prefixed string:

```
string msg = @"I want to learn ""c#""";
```

which results in:

> I want to learn "c#"

Comment: I needed this in my replace logic. string nullHideDecimal = @"<HideDecimal i:nil=""true""/>"; and then dataContractXML = dataContractXML.Replace(nullHideDecimal, "<HideDecimal>0</HideDecimal>");

Answer (score 30):

I use:

```
var value = "'Field1','Field2','Field3'".Replace("'", "\"");
```

as opposed to the equivalent

```
var value = "\"Field1\",\"Field2\",\"Field3\"";
```

Because the former has far less noise than the latter, making it easier to see typo's etc.

I use it a lot in unit tests.

Answer (score 17):

```
string str = @"""Hi, "" I am programmer";
```

OUTPUT - "Hi, " I am programmer

Answer (score 8):

Since .NET 7 you can use [raw string literals](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp-11-preview-updates/#raw-string-literals), which allows to declare strings without escaping symbols:

```cs
string text = """
I want to learn "C#"
""";
Console.WriteLine(text); // Prints string 'I want to learn "C#"'
```

If string does not start or end with double quote you can even make it single line:

```cs
string text = """I want to learn "C#"!""";
```

Answer (score 4):

Use escape characters for example this code:

```
var message = "I want to learn \"c#\"";
Console.WriteLine(message);
```

will output:

> I want to learn "c#"

Answer (score 1):

You can also declare a constant and use it each time. neat and avoids confusion:

```
const string myStrQuote = "\"";
```

Answer (score -4):

The Code:

`string myString = "Hello " + ((char)34) + " World." + ((char)34);`

Output will be:

> Hello "World."