# Using quotation marks in Javascript with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, button, quotes, double-quotes

I have written some code to update the player on the story as it progresses. When the player clicks a button they are greeted with some new text and some more options. So far so good, but when I pass a function call in with a parameter attached, I need both single and double quote marks. However, if I use both then this breaks the innerHTML. Code is as follows (can post HTML too if need be):

```
function buttonClicked(buttonid)  {
     switch(buttonid) {
    case "YesStart":
        document.getElementById("storybox").innerHTML = "Initially she fails to notice you and stares into the distance with dazed look of someone who has considered the exact point at which the universe might have ended, present within a kind of altered dimensionality that places her materially at a similar point of existence to you, while leaving her utterly absent from it in some other, more absolute sense. Two nuns scurry past her, heading towards a small, fluffy dog, who they pet while making cooing sounds; a stern man in an ill-fitting police officer's uniform eyes them suspiciously. This spectacle seems to rouse her from her trance, and she looks quizzically at them, tilting her head to one side, before spotting you out of the corner her eye and waving you over.</p><p>When you arrive at the hotel it is empty but for two bleary eyed reception staff who stare as you walk past. Deer-Wolf tells you this is the place where the murderer lives. He rents a different room each week, always under different assumed names. He tells people this is because he is married, and likes to take women back unnoticed. The staff have never seen one leave, but the room is always impeccably kept, so the uneasy feeling the hotel staff have about him has never yet been officially corroborated.</p>";
        break;
    case "NoStart":
        document.getElementById("storybox").innerHTML = "<p>You try to fall asleep in your bed but you cannot. Your heart is beating so fast you feel like it will fail. All night you are plagued by images of your still conscious body being cut open at autopsy. You wake up often. During the days you are afraid to be left alone. The only solace you have is a lady who calls herself Deer-Wolf, who texts you often and calls you on occasion. You find her voice comforting but you are still afraid, and feel that you will never be fully safe until you solve the case. You ask your friends for help, even offer to pay them to investigate but they either ignore you, decline, or tell you to go away. You are not sure if they believe you and are too scared, or if they think you are crazy. Either way, they won't help.</p><p>Do you choose to investigate?</p>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-success' id='yesbtn' onclick='buttonClicked('YesStart')'>Yes</button><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' id='nobtn' onclick='buttonClicked('NoStart')'>No</button>";
        break;
    default:
       console.log("Do you write your button function call correctly? Bad function call. Bad.");
    };

};
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: To lazy to translate... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456039/178988

Comment: Argh. JavaScript nested inside HTML nested inside JavaScript (which is probably nested inside HTML in turn). Trying to get all the escaping correct many levels down will give you a headache. Stop playing with strings and use `createElement`, `createTextNode`, `appendChild`, `setAttribute`, and `addEventListener` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to escape them with \.

```
"This is a string with \"quotation\" marks."
```

[How to include quotes in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458046/how-to-include-quotes-in-a-string)

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but it wasn't working. Let me try again.

Comment: You still have to distinguish between single and double quotation. For example, `"onclick='buttonClicked(\'NoStart\')'"` won't work, because you're using single quote for both the argument and parameter. `"onclick='buttonClicked(\"NoStart\")'"` will work.

Comment: Ah, great! Had a look over again and that does seems to be the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is HTML, I'd try using `&quot;` in the string.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function test1() {
  eval("console.log('\'text\'')");
}

function test2() {
  eval("console.log(\"'text'\")");
}

function test3() {
  eval("console.log('\\'text\\'')");
}
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: .25em;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="console.log("'text'")">Wrong</button>
<button onclick='console.log("'text'")'>Wrong too</button>
<br>
<button onclick="console.log(&quot;'text'&quot;)">Right</button>
<button onclick='console.log("&#39;text&#39;")'>Right too</button>
<button onclick="console.log(&quot;&#39;text&#39;&quot;)">And this one is right</button>
<br>
<button onclick="console.log('\'text\'')">Right with escaping</button>
<br><br>
<button onclick="test1()">Wrong in js</button>
<br>
<button onclick="test2()">Escaping outer in js</button>
<button onclick="test3()">Escaping inner in js js</button>
<br><br>
<button onclick=console.log("'text'")>And the final one - this way works too</button>
```

More information (in Russian): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456039/178988

Answer (score 0):

Choose one type of quote as the wrapper, e.g. `"`, then for attribute wrappers, use the other, e.g. `'`. If you then need any other embedded quotes, escape them like so `\'`.

```
document.getElementById("storybox").innerHTML = "Initially she fails to notice you and stares into the distance with dazed look of someone who has considered the exact point at which the universe might have ended, present within a kind of altered dimensionality that places her materially at a similar point of existence to you, while leaving her utterly absent from it in some other, more absolute sense. Two nuns scurry past her, heading towards a small, fluffy dog, who they pet while making cooing sounds; a stern man in an ill-fitting police officer\'s uniform eyes them suspiciously. This spectacle seems to rouse her from her trance, and she looks quizzically at them, tilting her head to one side, before spotting you out of the corner her eye and waving you over.</p><p>When you arrive at the hotel it is empty but for two bleary eyed reception staff who stare as you walk past. Deer-Wolf tells you this is the place where the murderer lives. He rents a different room each week, always under different assumed names. He tells people this is because he is married, and likes to take women back unnoticed. The staff have never seen one leave, but the room is always impeccably kept, so the uneasy feeling the hotel staff have about him has never yet been officially corroborated.</p>";
```

For future reference: please make more concise examples.