# self-hosted powershell doesn't realize variable within a string

Tags: powershell, self-hosting

I have a self-hosted PowerShell environment and I have following script

```
$one = 10
$two = "The value of one is $one"
```

When I run this snippet within the PowerShell ISE the result is as I expect

```
The value of one is 10
```

When I run this within my self hosted PowerShell environment the string isn't realized and the result is unchanged. Does anybody have an idea how to invoke the standard behavior?

Best regards,
zimmy

the full example

```
var script = $@"
            $one = 10
            $two = 'The value is $one'
     ";

var ps = PowerShell.Create();

ps.AddScript(script);
ps.Invoke();

var valueoftwo = ps.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.GetVariable("two");

Assert.Equal("The value is 10", valueoftwo);
// here the value is 'The value is $one'
```

Comment: What do you mean by self hosted PowerShell environment?

Comment: I reference to the nuget package Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssmblies, create a PowerShell object and a runspace and then run the script.

Comment: @zimmybln, do you have some code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I edited the question. See above.

Comment: Your powershell string is single quoted `$two = 'The value is $one'` inside the C# string. Single quoted strings don't do variable interpolation in PowerShell. You will need to embed double quotes inside your C# string with backslashes `$two = \"the value is $one\"` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3458058/478656

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot!