# Use Replace function to remove "{ characters from string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to remove `"{` and replace it with `{`. The following is the line of code that I'm currently using.

```
var MyString = DataString.Replace(@""{", "");
```

***The following is the error message I'm getting***
[image]

Please advise

Thanks

Comment: I believe this is not just any string but a Json response from somewhere. So it this really what you want? Or it is just a quick fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quote that you want to replace using two quotes, so for your example:

```
    var MyString = DataString.Replace(@"""{", "{");
```

Also see [How to include quotes in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458046/how-to-include-quotes-in-a-string) for alternatives to use quotes in strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting `JSON` data then what you really need is a `JSON Parser` for that. And if you just want to replace `"{` to `{` then you simply need to escape and replace the string like below:

```
// Suppose the variable named str has a value of Hello"{ wrapped in double quotes
var strReplaced = str.Replace("\"{", "{");
Console.WriteLine($"strReplaced: {strReplaced}");
// This will result in strReplaced: Hello{
```