# How to convert a string with delimiter to json string in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have a string

```
string myString = "KTC|2020|MPD|18/01/2021|I|O|B|ALST|";
```

I need to convert to the following format.

```
string convertedJsonString="{"compCode":"KTC","accountYear":"2020","shipmentNumber":"MPD","shipmentDate":"18/01/2021","shipmentType":"I","shipmentCategory":"M","fromLevelCode":"B","fromLocationCode":"ALST"}";
```

When I tried to write the code like the following,

```
string[] inputArray = input.Split("|");
string jsonString = @"{"+ " compCode "+ ":" + inputArray[0];
jsonString += "," + "accountYear" + ":" + inputArray[1] + "}";
```

I am getting the string like the following

{ compCode :KTC,accountYear:2020} Not in the required format.

Can you please give me some idea about how we can achieve this?

Comment: Your problem is you do not escape the quotation marks to escape them write: `string jsonString = "{\"compCode\": .... `

Comment: Converting to object and serializing is the cleanest, but if you want to persist with this approach you should check this out because you are missing the " - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458046/how-to-include-quotes-in-a-string

Answer (score 1):

Try generating an anonymous class and then serialize it:

```
var json = new { 
compCode = inputArray[0],
accountYear = inputArray[1],
shipmentNumber = inputArray[2],
shipmentDate=inputArray[3],
shipmentType = inputArray[4],
shipmentCategory=inputArray[5],
fromLevelCode=inputArray[6],
fromLocationCode=inputArray[7]
}

string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
```

Comment: @Edwin Your welcome, please don't forget to mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the key name for each json element you can create a map array and iterate over it.

```
string[] a = { "compCode", "accountYear" };
var json = "{";
var stringList = "KTC|2020|MPD|18/01/2021|I|O|B|ALST|".Split('|');
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { json += @",\"{a[i]}\": \"{stringList[i]}\"" ; }
json += "}";
```